# Why is index used in Update statement but not SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with about 5 million records.  I have a bitwise column called process_flag that has a non-clustered index on it.  When I do the following SELECT query it takes about 6 seconds.  As I would expect it doesn't use the index due to the complexity of the where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE process_flag & 4 = 4
```

However, if I perform the UPDATE statement below it takes milliseconds and does use the index.

```
UPDATE mytable SET process_flag = process_flag &~ 4 WHERE process_flag & 4 = 4
```

Can anyone explain why the index would be used on the UPDATE statement but not on the SELECT statement?

Comment: Try `WHERE process_flag >= 4 AND process_flag & 4 = 4;` (But, that still might not be enough to make the index enticing, since the issue is probably that it doesn't cover the `SELECT` - there are too many columns coming back through `*` that aren't in play for the update.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Add the second part as an answer: the UPDATE _only_ uses the one column, and so the index covers, where the SELECT needs more from the table.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn fair, but both points are relevant. :-)

Comment: Either way if it uses the index it will still have to do lookups back to the base table (for the `SELECT` to retrieve the missing columns and for the `UPDATE` as it needs to update the actual row too). Probably the difference is because for the `SELECT` if it decides to do a scan it doesn't have to do any additional work whereas for the `UPDATE` it still has to update the index rows anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why the SELECT doesn't use the index

The problem is that `SELECT *` requires obtaining all of the other columns that *aren't* covered by the index on the flag column. So, if more than a few rows are expected, and depending on the estimated *size* of the other columns, it is likely going to be cheaper for SQL Server to scan the clustered index instead of using the index and then performing a separate lookup for each individual row.

#### Why the UPDATE does use the index

To *find* the rows for the update, the other columns aren't relevant. SQL Server can efficiently scan (or potentially seek!) the narrow index to find the rows, then apply updates to the clustered index (and all non-clustered indexes) *after* those rows have been identified.

#### What you can do about it

1. As with any optimization, the first thing is to ask yourself if `SELECT *` is necessary.
2. If `SELECT *` (or at least *more than the columns currently in the index*) is necessary, then maybe you can widen the index via `INCLUDE`.
3. In general, it can be useful to provide SQL Server this additional (should be redundant) predicate, since it *can* allow a seek in some cases (I've written about this, long ago, [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/dry-principle-bitwise-operations)). This is unlikely to help if not in combination with `1.` and/or `2.`.

   ```
    WHERE flag_column >= 4 AND flag_column & 4 = 4
   ```

In the following example, you'll notice that `SELECT *` uses a clustered index scan, while just selecting a subset of columns uses a scan of the non-clustered index. When I add `3.`, that becomes a seek.

The updates both use the non-clustered index, as described, with again a seek resulting from adding the redundant where clause.

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7p00ee23)

Comment: Great answer thank you, a lot of take aways in there.  I will definitely look to limit the use of SELECT * and use INCLUDE more often but where that is not possible the flag_column > 4 to bring the index into play works very well too.